# docker : do not override base image entrypoint

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to have a docker image which extends mongo image and have ssh on it. I wrote this lines :

```
FROM mongo

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openssh-server

EXPOSE 22

RUN useradd -s /bin/bash -p $(openssl passwd -1 test) -d /home/nf2/ -m -G sudo test

CMD ["sh", "-c", "service ssh start", "bash"]
```

This starts only `ssh` and not `mongo`. If I remove the last line `mongod` is executed from the base image.

Any idea to run both commands in the same image ?

Comment: A Docker container typically only runs one process.  If you delete that `CMD` line, it will run MongoDB from the base image.  Why do you need either an ssh daemon or an interactive shell to work with a database?

Comment: I’m new to docker. I have to simulate my entreprise machines to run some scripts (COVID-19 restrictions). This scripts use ssh and scp to put and pull data on mongo machine. So i need both mongo and ssh running on the same  environnement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @David, CMD typically run one process so when you override this with `service ssh start` it will not run Mongo as it will overide base image `CMD` that run Mongo process.

Try to change `CMD` to start both processes.

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "service ssh start && mongod"]
```

But you should know in this if service ssh stop due to some reason you container will still keep running and it will die once Mongo process stop.
You can verify using below command

```
docker run  -dit --name test --rm abc && docker exec -it test bash -c "service ssh status"
ce30fa23eeb07f1e268008cce7566585ba1f98c0a3054cecb145443f3275a0d4
 * sshd is running
```

**Update:**

As mongod will only start Mongo process and no init DB will be happened so try to change your command for imitating DB.

```
FROM mongo
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openssh-server
ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=example
RUN useradd -s /bin/bash -p $(openssl passwd -1 test) -d /home/nf2/ -m -G 
CMD ["sh", "-c", "service ssh start && docker-entrypoint.sh mongod"]
```

Comment: I've tried it, it start them both. I can access to ssh (from the host) now but not mongo ... i've tried to expose again 27017 port but it didn't work : `docker run -it -p 27017:27017 -p 22:22 test`

Comment: can you just explain to me what means `docker-entrypoint.sh mongod`?

Comment: `docker-entrypoint.sh mongod` this comes from the mongo image which not only start the process but also construct DB etc

Comment: have you an idea on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62638487/docker-how-to-share-ssh-keys-between-containers ? :)

Comment: yeah, let me check.

Comment: @flywell please check.