# docker : how to share ssh-keys between containers?

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose, dockerfile, openssh

I've 4 containers configured like the following (`docker-compose.yml`):

```
version: '3'
networks:
  my-ntwk:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24
services:
  f-app:
    image: f-app
    tty: true
    container_name: f-app
    hostname: f-app.info.my
    ports:
      - "22:22"
    networks:
      my-ntwk:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.5
    extra_hosts:
      - "f-db.info.my:172.20.0.6"
      - "p-app.info.my:172.20.0.7"
      - "p-db.info.my:172.20.0.8"
    depends_on:
      - f-db
      - p-app
      - p-db
  f-db:
    image: f-db
    tty: true
    container_name: f-db
    hostname: f-db.info.my
    networks:
      my-ntwk:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.6
  p-app:
    image: p-app
    tty: true
    container_name: p-app
    hostname: p-app.info.my
    networks:
      my-ntwk:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.7
  p-db:
    image: p-db
    tty: true
    container_name: prod-db
    hostname: p-db.info.my
    networks:
      my-ntwk:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.8
```

Each image is build by the same `Dockerfile` :

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openssh-server

EXPOSE 22

RUN useradd -s /bin/bash -p $(openssl passwd -1 myuser) -d /home/nf2/ -m myuser

ENTRYPOINT service ssh start && bash
```

Now I want to be able to connect from `f-app` to any other machine without typing the password when running this line : `ssh myuser@f-db.info.my`.

I know that I need to exchange ssh-keys between the servers (thats not a problem). My problem is how to do it with docker containers and when (build or runtime)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing `ssh` without password you to need to create passwordless user along with configuring `SSH keys` in the container, plus you will also need to add `ssh keys` in the sources container plus public key should be added in the authorized of the destination container.

Here is the working Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:7

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openssh-server vim 

EXPOSE 22


RUN useradd -rm -d /home/nf2/ -s /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -u 1001 ubuntu
USER ubuntu
WORKDIR /home/ubuntu

RUN mkdir -p /home/nf2/.ssh/ && \
    chmod 0700 /home/nf2/.ssh  && \
    touch /home/nf2/.ssh/authorized_keys && \
    chmod 600 /home/nf2/.ssh/authorized_keys

COPY ssh-keys/ /keys/
RUN cat /keys/ssh_test.pub >> /home/nf2/.ssh/authorized_keys

USER root
ENTRYPOINT service ssh start && bash
```

docker-compose will remain same, here is the testing script that you can try.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo "start docker-compose"
docker-compose up -d
echo "list of containers"
docker-compose ps
echo "starting ssh test from f-db to f-app"
docker exec -it f-db sh -c "ssh -i /keys/ssh_test ubuntu@f-app"
```

For further detail, you can try the above working example [docker-container-ssh](https://github.com/Adiii717/docker-container-ssh)

```
git clone git@github.com:Adiii717/docker-container-ssh.git
cd docker-container-ssh; 
./test.sh
```

You can replace the keys as these were used for testing purpose only.

Comment: your solution is great, like always :) Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it helps :)

Comment: is there a way to avoid adding ssh -i /keys/ssh_test each time I use ssh or scp ?

Comment: yes you can add this key to default key. `ssh-add /keys/ssh_test`, add this command to docker-entrypoint. would be great if you can generate pull request for this git@github.com:Adiii717/docker-container-ssh.git

Comment: You can check the merge https://github.com/Adiii717/docker-container-ssh/pull/1, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you are using docker compose an easy choice is to forward SSH agent like that:

```
something:
    container_name: something
    volumes:
        - $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent # Forward local machine SSH key to docker
    environment:
        SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /ssh-agent
```

ssh-forwarding on macOS hosts - instead of mounting the path of `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, you have to mount this path - `/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock`

---

or you can do it like:

---

It's a harder problem if you need to use SSH at build time. For example if you're using `git clone`, or in my case `pip` and `npm` to download from a private repository.

The solution I found is to add your keys using the `--build-arg` flag. Then you can use the new experimental `--squash` command (added 1.13) to merge the layers so that the keys are no longer available after removal. Here's my solution:

**Build command**

```
$ docker build -t example --build-arg ssh_prv_key="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" --build-arg ssh_pub_key="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)" --squash .
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8

ARG ssh_prv_key
ARG ssh_pub_key

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        git \
        openssh-server \
        libmysqlclient-dev

# Authorize SSH Host
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh && \
    chmod 0700 /root/.ssh && \
    ssh-keyscan github.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts

# Add the keys and set permissions
RUN echo "$ssh_prv_key" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    echo "$ssh_pub_key" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openssh-server && \
    apt-get install -y openssh-client

EXPOSE 22

RUN useradd -s /bin/bash -p $(openssl passwd -1 myuser) -d /home/nf2/ -m myuser

ENTRYPOINT service ssh start && bash
```

---

If you're using Docker 1.13+ and/or have experimental features on you can append `--squash` to the build command which will merge the layers, removing the SSH keys and hiding them from `docker history`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I haven't managed to find a solution that works without a password, if you don't care your password is given in plain text (I think so because technically it's the same as setting no password as propose in accepted answer) you can install `sshpass` in addition of `openssh` then call your SSH command like this (I added the `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new` in order not to have the prompt to accept connection first time running SSH):

```
sshpass -p YourPassword ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new myuser@f-db.info.my
```